# I2C Communication using FTDI

Tags: python, i2c

I am using the FT2232H Mini Module to establish an i2c connection to the other board. For that, I am using some python library (PyFtdi) to communicate with the Mini module. I am providing 12 V external power supply to other board and based on connection explained in the web.

For 10k Pull up resistors as mentioned in the datasheet for the TI board. The slave address comes out to be 0x69. I am using this slave address to communicate using an i2c. But unfortunately, I am getting "NACK from slave".
I don't know what is the issue. I am able to get the i2c waveform data and clock.

```
i2c = I2cController()
```

Configure the first interface (IF/1) of the FTDI device as an I2C master:

```
i2c.configure('ftdi://ftdi:2232h/1')
```

Get a port to an I2C slave device

```
slave = i2c.get_port(0x69)
```

Read a register from the I2C slave

```
slave.read_from(0x00, 1)
```

I expect I could be able to access some of the resistors, but the actual result is:

```
pyftdi.i2c.I2cNackError: NACK from slave
```